# Create folder and export resolution ratios for artboard

Tags: javascript

After searching the internet, I was able to find a base JavaScript file in order to build upon for my project. Which is to create a Adobe Illustrator Script that will create the desired Folders and then export different resolution ratios for each artboard. This method is used in order to create Wallpapers of varying resolution ratios with a range of sizes.

I am looking for assistance with methods of cleaning the code which I have written, taking into consideration this is my first JavaScript project. I'm also looking for methods of slimming down the code by method of loops for the exporting for instance, due to not being able to figure out the correct logic with my various attempts.

```
//Closes Script if Program is not Open
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
main();
}
else alert('Cancelled by user');

function main() {
var document = app.activeDocument;
var afile = document.fullName;
var filename = afile.name.split('.')[0];

//Dialog to select Destination Folder
var folder = afile.parent.selectDlg("Export as CSS Layers (images only)...");

//Within Destination, check if folder exists, if not create the folder
if(folder !== null) {
    var folder0 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers");
    if(!folder0.exists) folder0.create();

    var folder1 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/5x4");
    if(!folder1.exists) folder1.create();

    var folder2 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/4x3");
    if(!folder2.exists) folder2.create();

    var folder3 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/3x2");
    if(!folder3.exists) folder3.create();

    var folder4 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/8x5");
    if(!folder4.exists) folder4.create();

    var folder5 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/5x3");
    if(!folder5.exists) folder5.create();

    var folder6 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/16x9");
    if(!folder6.exists) folder6.create();

    var folder7 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/17x9");
    if(!folder7.exists) folder7.create();

    var folder8 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/21x9");
    if(!folder8.exists) folder8.create();

//Outline PNG Export Setting
    var options = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
    options.antiAliasing = true;
    options.transparency = true;
    options.artBoardClipping = true;

//Specify Output Size for each Artboard Array
    var iconsx = [
        {"name": (filename + "_Transparent"), "width":3240, "height":3240},
    ];

    var icons0 = [
        {"name": (filename + "_Instagram"), "width":1080, "height":1080},
    ];

    var icons1 = [
        {"name": (filename + "_1280x1024"), "width":1280, "height":1024},
        {"name": (filename + "_2560x2048"), "width":2560, "height":2048},
    ];

    var icons2 = [
        {"name": (filename + "_320x240"), "width":320, "height":240},
        {"name": (filename + "_384x288"), "width":384, "height":288},
        {"name": (filename + "_640x480"), "width":640, "height":480},
        {"name": (filename + "_768x576"), "width":768, "height":576},
        {"name": (filename + "_800x600"), "width":800, "height":600},
        {"name": (filename + "_1024x768"), "width":1024, "height":768},
        {"name": (filename + "_1152x864"), "width":1152, "height":864},
        {"name": (filename + "_1280x960"), "width":1280, "height":960},
        {"name": (filename + "_1400x1050"), "width":1400, "height":1050},
        {"name": (filename + "_1440x1080"), "width":1440, "height":1080},
        {"name": (filename + "_1600x1200"), "width":1600, "height":1200},
        {"name": (filename + "_2048x1536"), "width":2048, "height":1536},
    ];  

    var icons3 = [
        {"name": (filename + "_480x320"), "width":480, "height":320},
        {"name": (filename + "_1152x768"), "width":1152, "height":768},
        {"name": (filename + "_1440x960"), "width":1440, "height":960},
    ];

    var icons4 = [
        {"name": (filename + "_320x200"), "width":320, "height":200},
        {"name": (filename + "_1280x800"), "width":1280, "height":800},
        {"name": (filename + "_1440x900"), "width":1440, "height":900},
        {"name": (filename + "_1680x1050"), "width":1680, "height":1050},
        {"name": (filename + "_1920x1200"), "width":1920, "height":1200},
        {"name": (filename + "_2560x1600"), "width":2560, "height":1600},
    ]; 

    var icons5 = [
        {"name": (filename + "_800x480"), "width":800, "height":480},
        {"name": (filename + "_1280x768"), "width":1280, "height":768},
    ];

    var icons6 = [
        {"name": (filename + "_854x480"), "width":854, "height":480},
        {"name": (filename + "_1024x576"), "width":1024, "height":576},
        {"name": (filename + "_1280x720"), "width":1280, "height":720},
        {"name": (filename + "_1366x768"), "width":1366, "height":768},
        {"name": (filename + "_1600x900"), "width":1600, "height":900},
        {"name": (filename + "_1920x1080"), "width":1920, "height":1080},
        {"name": (filename + "_2560x1440"), "width":2560, "height":1440},
        {"name": (filename + "_3840x2160"), "width":3840, "height":2160},
    ];

    var icons7 = [
        {"name": (filename + "_2048x1080"), "width":2048, "height":1080},
        {"name": (filename + "_4096x2160"), "width":4096, "height":2160},
    ];

    var icons8 = [
        {"name": (filename + "_2560x1080"), "width":2560, "height":1080},
    ];

//Set Active Artboard as the First Artboard in the Program
    document.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(0);

    var icon, file;

//Loop to Output each Resolution Specified Above for the Current Artboard
    for(var i = 0; i < iconsx.length; i++) {
        icon = iconsx[i]; 

//Hide layers for creating a Transparent Output File
        var layer0 = document.layers.getByName("Instagram");
        layer0.visible = ! layer0.visible;

        var layer1 = document.layers.getByName("Text");
        layer1.visible = ! layer1.visible;

        var layer2 = document.layers.getByName("Background");
        layer2.visible = ! layer2.visible;

        file = new File(folder.fsName + '/Wallpapers/' + icon.name + ".png");

        options.horizontalScale = 100 * (icon.width / document.width);
        options.verticalScale = 100 * (icon.height / document.height);

        document.exportFile(file,ExportType.PNG24,options);

//Unhide Layers which were previously set to hidden
        layer0.visible = ! layer0.visible;
        layer1.visible = ! layer1.visible;
        layer2.visible = ! layer2.visible;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < icons0.length; i++) {
        icon = icons0[i]; 

        file = new File(folder.fsName + '/Wallpapers/' + icon.name + ".png");

        options.horizontalScale = 100 * (icon.width / document.width);
        options.verticalScale = 100 * (icon.height / document.height);

        document.exportFile(file,ExportType.PNG24,options);
    }

    document.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(1);

    for(i = 0; i < icons1.length; i++)
    {
        icon = icons1[i]; 

        file = new File(folder.fsName + '/Wallpapers/5x4/' + icon.name + ".png");

        options.horizontalScale = 100 * (icon.width / document.width);
        options.verticalScale = 100 * (icon.height / document.height);

        document.exportFile(file,ExportType.PNG24,options);
    }

    document.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(2);

    for(i = 0; i < icons2.length; i++)
    {
        icon = icons2[i]; 

        file = new File(folder.fsName + '/Wallpapers/4x3/' + icon.name + ".png");

        options.horizontalScale = 100 * (icon.width / document.width);
        options.verticalScale = 100 * (icon.height / document.height);

        document.exportFile(file,ExportType.PNG24,options);
    }

    document.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(3);

    for(i = 0; i < icons3.length; i++)
    {
        icon = icons3[i]; 

        file = new File(folder.fsName + '/Wallpapers/3x2/' + icon.name + ".png");

        options.horizontalScale = 100 * (icon.width / document.width);
        options.verticalScale = 100 * (icon.height / document.height);

        document.exportFile(file,ExportType.PNG24,options);
    }

    document.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(4);

    for(i = 0; i < icons4.length; i++)
    {
        icon = icons4[i]; 

        file = new File(folder.fsName + '/Wallpapers/8x5/' + icon.name + ".png");

        options.horizontalScale = 100 * (icon.width / document.width);
        options.verticalScale = 100 * (icon.height / document.height);

        document.exportFile(file,ExportType.PNG24,options);
    }

    document.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(5);

    for(i = 0; i < icons5.length; i++)
    {
        icon = icons5[i]; 

        file = new File(folder.fsName + '/Wallpapers/5x3/' + icon.name + ".png");

        options.horizontalScale = 100 * (icon.width / document.width);
        options.verticalScale = 100 * (icon.height / document.height);

        document.exportFile(file,ExportType.PNG24,options);
    }

    document.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(6);

    for (i = 0; i < icons6.length; i++)
    {
        icon = icons6[i]; 

        file = new File(folder.fsName + '/Wallpapers/16x9/' + icon.name + ".png");

        options.horizontalScale = 100 * (icon.width / document.width);
        options.verticalScale = 100 * (icon.height / document.height);

        document.exportFile(file,ExportType.PNG24,options);
    }

    document.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(7);

    for(i = 0; i < icons7.length; i++)
    {
        icon = icons7[i]; 

        file = new File(folder.fsName + '/Wallpapers/17x9/' + icon.name + ".png");

        options.horizontalScale = 100 * (icon.width / document.width);
        options.verticalScale = 100 * (icon.height / document.height);

        document.exportFile(file,ExportType.PNG24,options);
    }   

    document.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(8);

    for(i = 0; i < icons8.length; i++)
    {
        icon = icons8[i]; 

        file = new File(folder.fsName + '/Wallpapers/21x9/' + icon.name + ".png");

        options.horizontalScale = 100 * (icon.width / document.width);
        options.verticalScale = 100 * (icon.height / document.height);

        document.exportFile(file,ExportType.PNG24,options);
        }
    }
}
```

I have placed some general comments throughout the code to allow for a greater understanding of the concept which is trying to be achieved. While it also helps with understanding the context at each step in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [D.R.Y.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

That is the main problem about your code: you are repeating yourself in many, many places.

---

For example, you are repeating yourself here:

```
var folder0 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers");
if(!folder0.exists) folder0.create();

var folder1 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/5x4");
if(!folder1.exists) folder1.create();

var folder2 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/4x3");
if(!folder2.exists) folder2.create();

var folder3 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/3x2");
if(!folder3.exists) folder3.create();

var folder4 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/8x5");
if(!folder4.exists) folder4.create();

var folder5 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/5x3");
if(!folder5.exists) folder5.create();

var folder6 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/16x9");
if(!folder6.exists) folder6.create();

var folder7 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/17x9");
if(!folder7.exists) folder7.create();

var folder8 = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers/21x9");
if(!folder8.exists) folder8.create();
```

> **Rule of thumb**: if you start to name your variables the same exact thing but with a number at the end, then it's probably time to use an
>   array.

Now, that (above) isn't the reason why you are repeating yourself here.

The reason is is that all the code here is very similar. The only difference? The size/name of the wall paper. This part:

```
"/Wallpapers/NxN"
```

To make this simpler, lets use a loop to populate an array of all these folders that you are trying to make.

But first, to help us not repeat ourselves, let's create an array of all the wall paper sizes. Like this:

```
var sizes = ["", "/5x4", "/4x3", "/3x2", ...];
```

This will help us later because, rather than hard coding these into the code like you did, while we are looping we can just grab these values from the array.

Now, let's create the loop.

```
for(var i = 0, length = sizes.length; i < length; i++) {

}
```

The rest of the code, which is only the body of the loop, is now really simple to implement: the only change you are making to the code is the variable name. Since we are using a loop, this variable name now becomes `i`.

```
folders[i] = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers" + sizes[i]);
```

See what is happening here? Using `i` and setting different indexes in the folder array is just like using `folder0`, `folder1`, etc.

Then, that small conditional you have at the end is just as easy to implement:

```
if(!folder[i].exists) folders[i].create();
```

Now, to bring it all together:

```
for(var i = 0, length = sizes.length; i < length; i++) {
    folders[i] = Folder(folder + "/Wallpapers" + sizes[i]);
    if(!folders[i].exists) folders[i].create();
}
```

---

You have a lot of code here, and you are repeating yourself in a lot of places just like you did in the example above.

I recommend you take this idea that I showed you above and apply it to rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you for providing comprehensive feedback and assisting me with a greater structure for work !!!
I was unable to figure out the correct use of variables and order for the loops before but have been able to successfully get it working now for all files and folders, with excellent speed.